# Find a range of multiple cells in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to enhance my current script. Sheet1 and Sheet2 contain only filepath names in column A. If a filepath in Sheet2 isn't found in Sheet1, it is copied over to sheet 3.

```
'row counter
x = 1
'Initiate Variables
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

'create a new sheet 3, delete old one if it exists
If Sheets.Count > 2 Then
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets(3).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End If

Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "Sheet3"

Set ws3 = wb.Sheets("Sheet3")

'Get row count to know how many times to loop
rowCount2 = ws2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

'compare filepaths from sheet2 to sheet1
'if there is a difference, that difference is put on sheet 3
For i = 1 To rowCount2
    FilePath = ws2.Cells(i, 1)
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
        Set CellId = .Find(What:=FilePath, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not CellId Is Nothing Then
        'do nothing if filepath is found in both sheets
        Else
            'put the filepath from file2 not found in file1, into
            'sheet 3
            ws3.Cells(x, 1) = FilePath
            x = x + 1
        End If
    End With
Next I
```

What I want to do, is be able to reference a range of cells to compare instead of just from column A. Instead of just file paths in column A, there will be last saved by in column B, Last opened by in column C, etc. So instead of just checking for difference in filepath, I want differences in multiple columns. So there might be the same filepaths, but it was opened by someone different on another day. I need to grab that difference. I don't know how to reference the range of multiple cells. So I need to fix up this section of code:

```
FilePath = ws2.Cells(i, 1)
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
```

And if there is an easier way to approach this I am open to advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `'do nothing if filepath is found in both sheets` section, place something like this:

```
k = ws2.Cells(1,ws2.Columns.Count).End(xlToleft).Column
For j = 2 to k
    If ws2.Cells(i, j).Value <> CellId.Offset(, j - 1).Value Then 
       CellId.EntireRow.Copy ws.Cells(x,1).EntireRow
       x = x +1
       Exit For
       'or whatever code you need to move to sheet3 
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't know the actual amount of columns, it will vary depending on the information pasted into sheets 1 and 2 (Both will have the same amount of columns though). Also just FYI, I need to compare from column A through last column used. If that entire row of cells' value isn't found in the other sheet, that entire row needs to be added in sheet3

Comment: Ok, from your code it seems like it loops through each column to find a difference. But, instead of just moving over the difference to ws3.cells(x, 1), I want to pretty much copy/paste that entire row that has a difference into corresponding columns on sheet3.

Comment: So, attempting this code, it seems to work. But when the rows are placed into sheet3, they're not formatted correctly. I tried Autofitting the entire sheet, that row, and using pastespecial. Any recommendations?

Comment: @rdan1 - I don't know what *not formatted correctly* means, but I suggest posting another question with more details to receive help

Comment: Is there a way to just set the used cells in sheet2 as a searchrange, and then run a find on that searchrange. You'd be individually using each row of data on sheet1 as the find object. Instead of just using one column for search range and a string as the find object. I'd want to use find with a range (row i). And the search range, pretty much the whole sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Dictionary when comparing multiple list.  This way I only iterate over each list one time.

```
Sub CopyMissingFileNames()
    Dim filepath As Range, Target As Range
    Dim dictFilePaths As Object
    Set dictFilePaths = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        For Each filepath In .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

            If Not dictFilePaths.Exists(filepath.Text) Then dictFilePaths.Add filepath.Text, ""
        Next

    End With


    With Worksheets("Sheet2")

        For Each filepath In .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If Not dictFilePaths.Exists(filepath.Text) Then
                Set Target = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

                filepath.EntireRow.Copy Target
            End If
        Next

    End With



End Sub
```

Comment: Although it does do exactly what mine does (except starts pasting after row1), this method is a little more advanced for a beginner like myself. I appreciate the feedback, are there any resources you could link that I could read to help me understand your methodology?

Comment: You should watch all TheWiseOwlTutorials on Youtube.  Here is the relavent one [Dictionary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dND4coLI_B8&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=42)

Comment: I will give it a look, appreciate it.